# Customizing the implementation for auto generated controllers using EmberCLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When using globals we could have defined `App.Controller`, `App.ObjectController` and `App.ArrayController` to control what class Ember will use to generate controllers.

With EmberCLI, I see documentation for routes - using `app/routes/basic.js`. This works fine.

Does it also work for views? What about controllers? How would I implement the 'basic' for each kind of controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works for just about any object Ember would generate, including controllers. If you look [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3347c3acffe55969515b3c43fc01f2600911445c/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/generate_controller.js#L29-L35) you can see that Ember looks for 3 different types of controllers to generate: `basic`, `object`, and `array`. You can override these defaults by creating the following files:

```
app/controllers/basic.js
app/controllers/object.js
app/controllers/array.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember is moving away from views and controllers in favor of components. (See the Routable Components section of [The Road to Ember 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15).) To that end, I don't believe `Ember-CLI` provides the ability to provide a `basic` implementation of each of these controllers in order to discourage their use. (At least I could not find anything from searching the code base.)